# Probability of an airline overbooking a flight

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The question states that an airline has flights of 8 passengers, but sells at most 10 tickets per flight. The chance that a passenger does not show up for a flight is $0.1$. The chance that $k$ amount of tickets are sold is given as follows:
$$k=6, p=0.3$$
$$k=7, p=0.3$$
$$k=8, p=0.25$$
$$k=9, p=0.1$$
$$k=10, p=0.05$$
It asks to find the chance that the amount of passengers who show up for the flight is greater than the amount of available seats

I started by modeling the people who show up by $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10,\, p=.9)$. I found $P(X > 8)$ by finding $1 - P(X=6)-P(X=7) - P(X = 8)$, but this answer was not correct.  I was thinking to solve this by finding $P(X > 8 | k > 8)$, but I'm not sure if this is correct, nor how to go about doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it a typo that your $P(X>8) = 1 - P(X=6)-P(X=7) - P(X = 8)$?  Shouldn't it be $P(X>8) = 1 - P(X=10)-P(X=9)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $9$ tickets are sold, the conditional probability of overbooking is
$$\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^9$$
If $10$ tickets are sold, the conditional probability of overbooking is
$$10\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^9+\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{10}$$
hence, the probability of overbooking is
\begin{align*}
&\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)
\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^9
+
\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)
\left(
10\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^9+\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{10}
\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{15109399071}{2\cdot 10^{11}}\\[4pt]
&\approx.076
\end{align*}

Comment: Argh, you're right.  apologies, my mistake.